# Fill data in input boxes automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have four input boxes. If the user fills the first box and clicks a button then it should autofill the remaining input boxes with the value user input in the first box. Can it be done using javascript? Or I should say prefill the textboxes with the last data entered by the user?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with JavaScript. What have you tried? People will be happier to help you if you show some effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On button click, call this function

```
function fillValuesInTextBoxes()
{
    var text = document.getElementById("firsttextbox").value;

    document.getElementById("secondtextbox").value = text;
    document.getElementById("thirdtextbox").value = text;
    document.getElementById("fourthtextbox").value = text;
}
```

Comment: Thanx. It works fine. But what to do if I want to fill the rest with the last data entered by the user? And not with a fixed data entered at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. For example:

```
 <form id="sampleForm">
     <input type="text" id="fromInput" />
     <input type="text" class="autofiller"/>
     <input type="text" class="autofiller"/>
     <input type="text" class="autofiller"/>
     <input type="button"value="Fill" id="filler" >
     <input type="button"value="Fill without jQuery" id="filler2" onClick="fillValuesNoJQuery()">
 </form>
```

with the javascript

```
 function fillValues() {
       var value = $("#fromInput").val();
       var fields= $(".autofiller");
       fields.each(function (i) {
         $(this).val(value);
       });
 }

 $("#filler").click(fillValues);
```

assuming you have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) aviable.
You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/yYRkM/

Although I would like to note that you shouldn't include jQuery just for this functionality... if you already have it, it's great, but else just go with a:

```
 fillValuesNoJQuery = function () {
       var value = document.getElementById("fromInput").value;
       var oForm = document.getElementById("sampleForm");
       var i = 0;
       while (el = oForm.elements[i++]) if (el.className == 'autofiller') el.value= value ;
 }
```

You can see that in action too: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/yYRkM/

Answer (score 0):

or if input:checkbox

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-identifier").checked=true; //or ="checked"
```