# How can i make autofill form in web browser?

Tags: javascript, .net, jsp

I'm new in programming. I want to make autofill typing program which can input saving data to explore input forms, like register form.

I searched all over and I finally find something similar with what I want to make.

here is the URL:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgHlK5iZbaE

**The question is)**

in this video, what language and toll did he use? and how can he make these?

and can I make these program with JSP or javascript?

Please give me some hint. it will save my life. thanks

---

(add comment by writer in 20161205) really really appreciate for your answering.

I should add comment to clearly deliver my request.

What I want to make is to make auto-typing program to another website for user.

for example, there are lots of websites like facebook, google, and so on, and they have same request of typing in their register page like name, where you live, phone num, e-mail, birth ... etc

so, what i want to make is to save all information on databases of my program, and when user visited the website like Facebook register page, or Google register page, with one button clicked, my program will type the saving information just in 3 seconds.

surely, i should do customized program for each websites.

Please let me know the hints of the program! Thanks

Comment: For that if you want to browser to autofill the saved values in browser then you to add attribute `autocomplete='on'` in the form. And if you want to do it manually then get the values and fill them through `value='my auto fill value'` in form

Comment: thanks for your rely Dherya! but I incorrectly described what i wanted. I updated and edited the writing. please, read and rely again. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgHlK5iZbaE),he has developed a windows application using c#, that application. You can develop such kind of application but that will not fulfill your need, as you need to customize it every time for different registration forms.
Instead,you can prefer to make a auto-fill kind of application using javascript, using [bookmarklet](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154).
Inside the bookmarklet you can write javascript code to get the DOM element (using `document.getElementById("name")`) and write an data to that field.

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226371/fill-data-in-input-boxes-automaticaly) to get the element and write data to it.

Comment: thanks for your rely Nitin! but I incorrectly described what i wanted. I updated and edited the writing. please, read and rely again. thanks